# Graphic card maximum supported resolution

Tags: nvidia, ati, graphics, intel, vga

How can I get the maximum supported resolution for the graphic card? I'm looking for a terminal command to see if the graphic card supports a 4K display.

If there is no all-in-one command, then I'm interested in a command for main grapic card manufacturers Intel, Nvidia and ATI/AMD (open source & proprietary driver).

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a command, but [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/361753) may help. Quoted here.

> For Nvidia based cards of all varieties I would have gone straight to the Nvidia website rather than the  reseller (EVGA, XFX or whoever) and checked out the specifications of the card there.
>
> Picking one at random the [Geforce GTX 570](http://uk.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-570/specifications) specifications page immediately lists the maximum resolutions for both VGA cable and digital links:
>
> ```
> 2560x1600 Maximum Digital Resolution
> 2048x1536 Maximum VGA Resolution
> ```
>
> And it appears to be true for pretty much all of their graphics processors.  Just find their specifications page and the information is right there.
>
> Similarly AMD do the same for their graphics processors, so if you are looking at a Radeon based graphics card then again just completely ignore the reseller and go straight to AMD and find their specifications sheet.
>
> Picking one at random again the [Radeon HD 6970](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/amd-radeon-hd-6000/hd-6970/Pages/amd-radeon-hd-6970-overview.aspx#2) has, hidden near the bottom of their specifications page (in amongst a huge wodge of information you'll not care about) shows:
>
> ```
> DisplayPort 1.2
>     Max resolution: 2560x1600 per display
>     Multi-Stream Transport
>     21.6 Gbps bandwidth
>     High bit-rate audio
> HDMI 1.4a with Stereoscopic 3D Frame Packing Format, Deep Color, xvYCC wide gamut support, and high bit-rate audio
>     Max resolution: 1920x1200
> Dual-link DVI with HDCP
>     Max resolution: 2560x1600
> VGA
>     Max resolution: 2048x1536
> ```
>
> So basically just ignore the reseller, as they'll just be throwing impressive sounding numbers at you in a bid to get you to buy their products, while the **actual chip makers** will tell you what it can actually do.
>
> Basically just search either the Nvidia or AMD sites for whatever graphics processor you are looking at and you should, somewhere on the specifications page, find the information you are after.